# ImageMagick and OpenMP, use all cpu os a cluster?

Tags: imagemagick, openmp

I know i can use ImageMagick with OpenMP to use all cores of my CPU, but the question is: Can i use all the cores of my 10 computer cluster? or imagemagick will only use the cores of my local CPU?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

OpenMP is based on the fork-join paradigm which is bound to shared-memory systems because of the very nature of the fork function. Thus, you won't be able to use all the cores of your cluster since they don't share their memory. OpenMP-enabled programs are then limited to cores that share their memory (cores from the local CPU).

There is a way around this, though, but it may not be worth it. You can simulate a virtual NUMA architecture over your 10 computer cluster and execute ImageMagick on this virtual machine. ImageMagick will hence believe it runs on a single system containing all your cores. That's what [ScaleMP](http://www.scalemp.com/) offers with their vSMP software. But the performance gains are strongly related to the program's memory accesses, as they might occur over network in this VM, which is magnitudes slower than cache or RAM access. You may get a significant performance hit depending on how memory is accessed in ImageMagick.

In order to directly perform what you ask, instead of trying to use OpenMP outside its use cases, you could use a Message-Passing Interface (MPI) framework (such as [OpenMPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/)) to parallelize the program over multiple networked computers. That would require to rewrite the parallel portion of ImageMagick to use OpenMPI instead, which may be a pretty daunting task depending on ImageMagick's code base.